# Postgres Order data using a different element data type

Tags: postgresql

I have a model in postgres with a Char data type field.
In this Char data type, I have the need to basically register numbers but I cannot record them as Integer.

If I try to ORDER data using default data type (Char), I get:

```
82
821
8219 (correct position as Char, but wrong position as an Integer)
822
823
824
825
826
827 
828
829
```

I need to ORDER this char data as an Integer element so I can get the value "8219" into the correct position at the bottom of the list.

I have tried to use ORDER_BY **INT(**field_name**)** but no luck.

I have tried to use ORDER_BY INT(field_name) but no luck.

Comment: The real solution is to store your data in an integer column, but if you really want the order by to work try `order by field_name::integer`, noting that this won't work if there's non-integer data in the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I create this schema

```
create table mytable(
    something char(12)
);

insert into mytable(something)
values
('82'),
('821'),
('8219'),
('822'),
('823'),
('824'),
('825'),
('826'),
('827 '),
('828'),
('829');
```

and run this query:

```
select something
from mytable
order by something::integer;
```

Then I get correct results:

[image]

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/794bf/1

The idea is that you can convert the field to `integer` in the `order by` clause, so the values are compared as integers. The reason for the behavior is that if you compare strings, then '12' is "smaller" than '9', because strings are compared by each of their characters and wherever there is a difference, the character that's greater than the other decides the comparison. If all the character comparisons were yielding the same characters, then the longer string is "greater". This is why you wanted to compare them as integers.

Now, you should also ask yourself whether it makes sense for any reason to store the data for this field as char rather than integer. If there is no such reason, then you can alter the table and change the type of the field.

EDIT

Belayer raised a problem that may occur when a non-numeric char is being stored. Consequently, I updated the fiddle, which now can be found at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bc2c4a/5

First, I added some other values to it:

```
create table mytable(
    something char(12)
);

insert into mytable(something)
values
('82'),
('821'),
('8219'),
('822'),
('823'),
('824'),
('825'),
('826'),
('827 '),
('828'),
('829'),
('not a number'),
('3.14'),
(null),
(-3),
(-3.14);
```

We have a non-numeric value (`'not a number'`), a numerically float (`'3.14'`), `null` and some negatives (`'-3'` and `'-3.14'`, respectively).

This is how we can sort them as floats:

```
select something
from mytable
order by case when textregexeq(something,'^(-)?[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$') then something::float else null end;
```

The regex specifies that it may start with a -, then it continues with any number of digits and it may and with a dot following at least a digit. Any value corresponding to this regex will have its `float` conversion being evaluated when sorting, other values will have `null`.

And this is if we want them to be sorted by integers:

```
select something
from mytable
order by case when textregexeq(something,'^(-)?[[:digit:]]+?$') then something::integer else null end;
```

Note that there are two differences. First, we removed the "may end with a dot following with at least a digit" part from the regex and second, we convert the value to integer.

In both cases we use a `case`-`when` approach, that is, we check whether the value can be converted to the type we intend to use in our comparison and if so, we will use its conversion as its representative during the sorting. Otherwise, we default it to something, I used `null` as a default, but that can be changed to something else if needed.

Comment: If you keep the column as `char` then make sure you handle the exception *SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "..."*. Eventually **it will occur**.

Comment: @Belayer thanks for the observation. Edited my answer to cover that scenario.